# DxaPropertyMarkup() for List<> in model

Tags: dxa, experience-manager, dxa-1.7

I am having partial that renders:

```
@model List<AccessoryGroupModel>
```

I tried to create DxaPropertyMarkup() for items like this:

```
int i = 0;
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="u-flow" @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => item)>
```

or  this:

```
<div class="u-flow" @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model, i++)>
```

But nothing works. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Html.DxaPropertyMarkup` extension method is intended for rendering (guess what... :-)) property markup.  For that purpose, you should provide a lambda expression which resolves to a property of an Entity Model.

You are trying to provide it a lambda expression which resolves to the Model itself. That doesn't work, indeed.

Maybe you actually wanted to render entity markup? In that case, use `Html.DxaEntityMarkup`. That one does expect a lambda which resolved to a Model as a whole.